# Simple SQL update query can't figure out

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

table1:

```
client     report_date     date_of_analysis
554        30.12.2013      15.01.2014
554        30.12.2013      25.01.2014
554        30.12.2012      15.01.2013
554        30.12.2012      28.01.2013
554        30.12.2011      15.01.2012
556        30.12.2013      15.01.2014
556        30.12.2012      15.01.2013
556        30.12.2011      15.01.2012
556        30.12.2011      05.01.2012
```

I want to update the client number with x in front of it when there are two reports and the date of analysis is older.

In this case it should update one client 554 with the date of analysis 15.01.2014. for report date 30.12.2013. should now be 'x554'.

I tried:

```
update table1 
set client= 'x'+client
where date_of_analysis<max(date_of_analysis)
```

but this doesn't work

THE RESULTSET WOULD BE:

```
client     report_date     date_of_analysis
X554       30.12.2013      15.01.2014
554        30.12.2013      25.01.2014
X554       30.12.2012      15.01.2013
554        30.12.2012      28.01.2013
554        30.12.2011      15.01.2012
556        30.12.2013      15.01.2014
556        30.12.2012      15.01.2013
556        30.12.2011      15.01.2012
X556       30.12.2011      05.01.2012
```

Comment: Whats the data type for `client`?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Does it show any error message? And what are you trying to achieve with dat_analysis<dat_analysis?

Comment: yes, it shows an error message about the where statement

Comment: @user3279834 Do you think that perhaps we can see the error message? Or is it too much trouble?

Comment: Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------the problem is in this method of comparing the dates

Comment: Help me understand why you decided to change the filter on your `UPDATE` statement that's causing the error?

Comment: You can't use an aggregate like `MAX` in a `WHERE` clause.  See either my or t-clausen's answer below for alternate methods.

Comment: @user3279834, can you include the expected resultset?

Comment: the expected resultset would be:client      report_date           date_of_analysis
x554        30.12.2013.            15.01.2014.
 554        30.12.2013.            25.01.2014.
x554        30.12.2012.            15.01.2013.
 554        30.12.2012.            28.01.2013.
 554        30.12.2011.            15.01.2012.
 556        30.12.2013.            15.01.2014.
 556        30.12.2012.            15.01.2013.
 556        30.12.2011.            15.01.2012.
x556        30.12.2011.            05.01.2012

Comment: Please put it into the body of your question, not a comment.

Comment: i put it up there in the question, sorry

Comment: @user3279834 I have edited your question. "I have table data like this" but then no data? I hope you have learned from the comments to write better questions that do not make us waste our time. Your question has 3 downvotes and 1 close vote at this moment, all because you did not take the time to ask yourself "Is this question written so that it invites others to help me?"

Comment: i will keep that in mind next time, but there was a table with the data, i dont know how it got erased... :S probably you deleted it when editing the post @Jan Doggen

Comment: You did in the 6th edit ;-), I did not think of checking old edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution to this will be:

```
update  t1
set client= 'x'+client
FROM table1 t1
where EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Client = t1.Client
    AND date_of_analysis > t1.date_of_analysis
    AND report_date = t1.report_date)
AND LEFT(Client, 1) <> 'x'
```

Which will add an X to any client name on a row where there is a newer record for the same client.

Comment: its supposed to update only the values where the report for the same date exists twice or more and has a smaller analysis date than the highest analysis date for that report

Comment: If you need to check for the date I can add another line in there, otherwise that's what this does.

Comment: this doesnt check the date of the report, so it adds the x on every client that has as smaller analysis date than the biggest one

Comment: @user3279834 the revised version does, try now

Comment: Yeah, it does.  If you want to clarify you requirements please do, but as you explained this issue this solves it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming date_of_analysis is a datetime or date

```
;with x as
(
select client, date_of_analysis, 
  row_number() over (partition by client, report_date 
    order by date_of_analysis desc) rn
from <table>
where client not like 'x%'
)
update x
set client = 'x' + client
where rn > 1
```